# Transfer Paypal subscriptions to CiviCRM

Tags: recurring-contributions, paypal

is it possible to migrate existing paypal subscriptions (not created with CiviCRM) to CiviCRM?
I tried:

1. to create a recurring contribution with Paypal invoice Id in the field `civicrm_contribution_recur.invoice_id`
2. to activate PayPal IPN

Do you know what other steps need to be taken?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Here's a similar question: [What are my options for importing recurring contributions?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7146/what-are-my-options-for-importing-recurring-contributions)

The subscription information held at paypal includes the IPN url (https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/IPNIntro/), which is how paypal communicates about new payments made as part of the subscription. As far as I know, you can't modify the IPN url. If you had a way of redirecting or proxying those ipn calls to the equivalent CiviCRM ipn, you might get it working.